# SSRS Matrix Report : Colors condition

Tags: sql, matrix, reporting-services

I have a matrix table created with Rows as Days ,Columns as Months and quantity of rainfall as the data field(got all this information from same table 'Rainfall'). I have taken this data from a dataset containing multiple tables in SQL. All of this information displays properly.
Now I have many tables with date field in my dataset in tables other than 'Rainfall'.
In the data field of the matix I need to be able to add my own colors using a Switch case.
The Condition I need is "if a certain date from one table matches the date in my report then i want xxx colour."
eg: there is a table called fertilization which has 3 dates. Now if these 3 dates also exists in my matrix then that block should be colored blue.

Can anyone help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can also manage it from sql side while retrieving data from Rainfall table.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using by right clicking  the field that you want the dynamic color on and selecting properties. Select Border and then where it says color hit, click the Fx button. Here you can write a custom expression that will change the background color based upon your code.